# Unity app crashing on android version 5.0.1, unity version 5.3.4f1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I create a project and just add a plane object (so that I can minimize resources and see if that's the problem), but when I Build&Run to my android device I get a blank screen, then the device returns to the home screen saying that the application stopped.  I've looked around for solutions but I'm not getting anywhere.

My unity version: 5.3.4f1

My android version: 5.0.1 on Samsung phone.

EDIT:  It appears to only happened with virtual reality enabled.  I need this enabled so I'm not too sure what else to be looking for.

Comment: Just tried it then - didn't work

Comment: Hey, have you solved your problem?

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply.  I tried using the cardboard sdk and have no problems with.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn Off : PlayerSettings > Auto Graphics API
- Remove : OpenGLES3

This will force the player to render in OpenGLES2. And it will work fine on devices.